# Entity framework loads entire object graph when using include on parent object combined with a where() statement

Tags: .net, entity-framework, relationship

Ok, so I have set `LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` and I am now using `include()` to load the related objects I need. This works (mostly) just fine but with one exception. When including a parent object followed by a `where()` statement the parent object includes its entitre object graph. Not what I want.

For instance

```
_currentEntity.Include(x => x.Parent).Where(x => x.ParentId == 1);
```

returns th entire object graph while

```
_currentEntity.Include(x => x.Parent);
```

only includes the current object and it's parent object.

My question is, why is Entity Framework so stupid or am I missing some vital knowledge?

Thanks!

Comment: It's doing what you told it to do. You told it to get all parent entities ensuring the *current* entity has a ParentID of 1 (which I suspect it does). Check the SQL statements generated by the two queries

Comment: Hi, but it doesn't matter if I take `Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)`, it still returns the parent's entire object graph. You say "It's doing what you told it to do" but I only asked it to return the parent object, not the parent's object and all of it's nested child objects. I really don't see where I ask that, compared to when doing an include without a `Where()`. Could you explain a little bit further please.

Comment: What do you mean by "its entire object graph"? What _part_ of the `Parent` do you see loaded that you don't expect? EF will load all scalar properties, and fill in any navigational properties that are already present in your object context (e.g. `Parent.Children` will contain all this parent's children that you retrieved using the same context, it will match them on `ParentId`).

Comment: Say `Parent` has childs1, childs2, childs3 and theese childs have their own childs. In that case I excpect Parent to set theese children to null if I don't excplitely ask for them. Now they are loaded as well in the above scenario.

Comment: I gave a few more pointers in that comment than just the first question. _Do_ you load other child entities using the same context? Does the issue also occur when you use this code inside a `using (var context = new YourContext())  { ... }` block?

Comment: Sorry, to eager (EF joke). I do load other children using the same context. So I tried without loading any other children and in it's own context and got the same result. Even if I say this object doesn't include any child collections the parent includes it child collections, and it's child collections and so on.